# I'm not a narcissist, I promise!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Mostly, I tell the truth, but I can sometimes lie,
>   If you're skinny, fat, bald, or tall, I can tell you why.
>
> Reassurance is what you seek from me, though I'm not the best,
>   Really, I can only look skin deep, I can't figure out the rest.
>
> Odd, I stand before you, trapped, never to escape,
>   Returning your surprise, my mouth stands agape.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it is

> your reflection

Mostly, I tell the truth, but I can sometimes lie,

> your reflection is exact but not if the mirror isn't plane

If you're skinny, fat, bald, or tall, I can tell you why.

> your reflection looks like you

Reassurance is what you seek from me, though I'm not the best,

> Am I good looking for my date tonight?

Really, I can only look skin deep, I can't figure out the rest.

> a reflection cant show your thoughts

Odd, I stand before you, trapped, never to escape,

> the reflection can only be there if you're in front of the mirror

Returning your surprise, my mouth stands agape.

> and it mimics everything you do

Comment: Excellent job, you got it! This was solved so quickly that I can't accept it quite yet.

Comment: The fact that "narcissist" is in the title is a big clue too.

Answer (score 6):

Are you a

> Mirror

Mostly, I tell the truth, but I can sometimes lie,
If you're skinny, fat, bald, or tall, I can tell you why.

> Mirrors show what something is unless it is a fun house mirror. and It will show if you are bald or tall.

Reassurance is what you seek from me, though I'm not the best,
Really, I can only look skin deep, I can't figure out the rest.

> You check yourself in the mirror for assurance, and you cannot see inner beauty.

Odd, I stand before you, trapped, never to escape,
Returning your surprise, my mouth stands agape.

> It sands in front of you still, showing you for who you are.

Also

> The first letter of each line spells "mirror".

And

> Regarding the title, narcissists tend to gaze at themselves in the mirror.

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for, but you're on the right track.